# TFS merge changes not detected

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I have 2 branches (A and B) and the situation looks as follows:

On branch B, for one file I clicked *Get specific version* and picked the first version of this file. I then switched to branch A to merge version from branch A to B but it tells me that there are no changes to be merged. When I click compare on both files there are many changes

Answer (score 2):

After doing the "`Get Specific version`" you need to check out every file in the changeset manually (right-click, check-out). Be sure that you have the "`Get latest on checkout`" turned off.

After that perform a get latest, which will prompt you to merge. This is going to be a more tricky merge, since Visual Studio will assume that the newer version is what you want. When you're satisfied (you can keep local version), check in the code. Then merge branches.

You can also try "`Get This Version`" on the changeset. This is MUCH quicker than "`Get Specific version`" because you don't have to download the whole repo again.

***Follow below steps to do that:***

1) Go to ***Tools-->Options***, select ***Source Control-->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server***.  Un-check 2 options shown below.
[image]

2) For the file you'd like to edit, select the file, right click and **View History**.  In the history screen, select the version you would like to edit. Right click and select ***Get This Version***.

[image]

3) In Solution Explorer, double click the file and it should open the version you selected in the History view.

[image]

4) Make your edits and ***Check-In***.  You will get a **Resolve Conflicts** screen.  From there either **Merge Changes In Merge Tool** or select **Keep Local Version** to check in the file as is.

[image]

5)  Merge branches.